# Installing a .cer file

Tags: firefox

I have a cert.cer certificate file for my Mozilla Firefox. I don't have any clue how to go about installing it for my system. Any guidance would be of great help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to the Firefox menu → **Edit** → **Preferences**
2. Click on the **Advanced** tab
3. Click on the **Encryption** tab below *Advanced* tab.
4. Click **View certificates**
5. In the *Certificate manager* window, Click on the **Import** button. Then locate the .cer file, and then click **Open**. The cert file will be imported.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I am able to access the websites which were blocked for me but still am not able to ping the url from terminal or either telnet it . Any idea ?

Comment: You cannot ping an "url". If the url is `http://server.net/blah/blah/`, then you can `ping server.net`, but not `http://server.net` or `http://server.net/blah/blah/`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familier with CLI mode..

then you can just run below command

> sudo cp -rvf /path/of/abc.cer /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/abc.crt

Remember one thing... you have to rename that cer file into crt file like above command.